# NetSuite WMS Mobile App Changes are not being updated in the mobile app

Tags: mobile, version-control, netsuite, wms

I am doing a customization on SCM Mobile app. When a change is made, the mobile app needs to be updated for changes to take affect.

[image: Mobile Application List]

Problem I have is changes are not flowing through to the mobile app.
The script that runs is Mobile - Scheduled Generate App Config. I changed the log level to debug to see of there's any errors, but there's no errors happening. Also strange thing is, this update script usually takes around 5 mins to run, but now it runs in seconds. I have also tried deleting all the custom and start from scratch, but that also doesn't work and now I am not able to do any customisation on the mobile app as none of the changes is showing up.

Even when reconfiguring a standard mobile process and changing a label, doesn't show in the mobile app.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas of what I can try to resolve this?

Looks like something has broken withing the Scheduled Generate App Config script and none of my changes are being updated in the mobile app. Tried updating the WMS suitelet with no luck.